# Remove the error indicator from a previously-validated EditText widget

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am using an EditText widget, and I am validating it with the `setError()` method of EditText and it validates correctly.

But I have an button in the same screen that redirects to another activity. And when I press back button and come back to the screen the validation still appears.

So on the activity `OnPause` event I want to remove the validation of the EditText. How is it possible.

Answer (score 312, accepted):

```
protected void onPause () {
    TextView textView = ...; // fetch it as appropriate
    textView.setError(null);
}
```

Because as mentioned in the documentation:

> If the error is null, the error message and icon will be cleared.

Comment: Wow, so aside from NullPointerException, null value was really put into good use. LOL

Answer (score 20):

### In Kotlin:

```
editText.error = null
```

### Kotlin Extension Function:

To make it more readable, you could add this extension function

```
fun EditText.clearError() {
    error = null
}
```

### In Java:

```
editText.setError(null);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also do it using following :

```
protected void onPause () {    
    mEditText.setError(null);//removes error
    mEditText.clearFocus();    //clear focus from edittext
}
```

Answer (score 4):

just put `.setError(null)` at the end of the EditText.

```
mEditText.setError(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

In kotlin you can simply acces the property using property access syntax wich is

```
protected void onPause () {
    EditText mEditText = ...; // fetch it as appropriate
    mEditText.error = null
}
```