# how to hide set error into edit text Android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have two `EditText` and i set error when the edit text is empty , but the problem is when the `EditText` take value , the error still show , like this:

[image]

This is my code :

```
 String username=  edit_text_username.getText().toString();
    String password = edit_text_password.getText().toString();
    if (username.equals("")) {
        progressDialogLogin.dismiss();
        layoutUsername.setError(" required!");
        Layoutpassword.requestFocus();
    }
    else if (password.equals("")) {
        progressDialogLogin.dismiss();
        Layoutpassword.setError(" required!");
    }

        else {
```

any idea ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove error from EditText](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10206799/remove-error-from-edittext)

Comment: In the else part add layoutUsername.setErrorEnabled(false); Layoutpassword.setErrorEnabled(false); and try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
edtUserName.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if (edtUserName.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0) {
                    usernameLayout.setError(null);

                }
            }
        });
```

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 2):

You can add TextChangedListener to check if empty/not empty. for example:

```
edit_text_username.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (s.toString().length() > 0){
                layoutUsername.setError("");
            } else {
                layoutUsername.setError("user name required");
            }
        }
    });
```

in case you want to validate when login button clicked, you can use like this:

```
String username=  edit_text_username.getText().toString();
String password = edit_text_password.getText().toString();
loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (username.equals("")) {
                    progressDialogLogin.dismiss();
                    layoutUsername.setError(" required!");
                    Layoutpassword.requestFocus();
                } else {
                    layoutUsername.setError("");
                }
                if (password.equals("")) {
                    progressDialogLogin.dismiss();
                    Layoutpassword.setError(" required!");
                } else {
                    Layoutpassword.setError("");
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: @MoayedI.Alayseh you need to check both condition, when input invalid (display error), and when input valid (hide error), please check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout` to show error in Edittext :

**.xml** code :

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
android:id="@+id/input_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/input"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/hint" />
```

**strings.xml**

```
<string name="err_msg">required!</string>
```

**Java** Code :

```
TextInputLayout inputLayout = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.input_layout);
EditText input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input);


 // to show error use this code 
 inputLayout .setError(getString(R.string.err_msg));
```

Answer (score 0):

more efficient approach would be :

```
  private boolean validatePassword() {
        if (pass.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
            pass.setError(getString(R.string.err_msg_pass));
            requestFocus(text_pass);
            return false;
        }else if(pass.getText().toString().length()<8) {
            pass.setError(getString(R.string.err_msg_pass_length));
            requestFocus(text_pass);
            return false;
        }else {
            text_pass.setErrorEnabled(false);
        }
        return true;
    }
```